# How can I wrap up this anonymous function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary item as follows:

```
  'spot': lambda: quandl.get("LBMA/GOLD")['USD (AM)']
```

where calling `my_dict['spot']()` executes this function.

I need to wrap it up in a way that doesn't use `lambda`, as `pickle` doesn't support it. What tricks can I use?

Comment: If you use `import dill` you can pickle lambdas...

Comment: I'm using concurrent.futures ProcessPoolExecutor(). Will it just take over from Pickle?

Comment: So why not define a function object instead? That can be pickled just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would pass the function without evaluating it? It needs to be evaluated later